# Error of 25.0.0 while compiling the project

Tags: android

I have a project which was running fine till date. Suddenly today facing these issue :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.4.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.4.0
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/cardview-v7-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/25.0.0/customtabs-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/Android Studio/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.pom
         file:/D:/NewEclips/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.0/support-v4-25.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         Yokura-Seeker:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0
```

I also dont have 25.0.0 in my sdk, havnt still downloaded it, and also my compile version is 23.0.2 then y is it searching for 25.0.0?

EDIT :

the Exact issue i am facing now is that i am using

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

in gradle for facebook.

and in this library it is using 25.0.0 so how do i avoid that?

Comment: check your build.gradle file.Somewhere may be you forget to edit

Comment: "Suddenly today facing these issue": this may be related to the use of a wildcard version here `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`. Always use fixed versions to avoid surprises.

Comment: same problem here just now. I am using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' Why is asking me for 25? I did not change anything in the lat days????? Any Android Studio update? I am running on Ubuntu. I am also using 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

Comment: Answer here, it looks facebook updated his SDK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321265/android-studio-suddenly-started-to-display-unable-to-resolve-com-android-support

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since you didn't specify exact version of facebook SDK: `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`, it uses any version (latest probably), which probably targets the latest SDK (25), and requires the latest support library versions.
So you have 2 ways to fix it:

1. install missing libraries, and probably target SDK 25 in your project
2. use some exact version of facebook SDK, which does not target latest Android SDK

Comment: Can you giveme the exact version of facebook?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk choose version you need from here

Comment: @ParthAnjaria, looks like it is targetting API 25 since version 4.17.0. So the version before it is 4.16.1

Answer (score 5):

just replace the facebook compile version ,Because in latest version Support lib is updated to the SDK version 25.
**compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'**
just go to this link to check change logs of SDK
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR Just install API 25 and update everything in SDK Manager.

Comment: I IGNORED YOUR ANSWER AND CAME BACK AFTER 3 HOURS AND IT SOLVED THE DAMN ISSUE OFCOURSE I DIDNT HAVE API 25 GOD WHY ME