# f8app react-native run-android failed

Tags: android, git, react-native

I cloned git project https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app

I do all the instructions. But when I try to run the project (run-android) error occurs.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/Users/Mastermind/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
            file:/Users/Mastermind/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Desktop/ReactNative/f8app/node_modules/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Desktop/ReactNative/f8app/node_modules/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.pom
            file:/Users/Mastermind/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/appcompat-v7-25.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 20.189 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: You are likely to be missing the Android SDK version 25. Install it via the Android SDK Manager and try again.

Comment: @martinarroyo i installed missing android sdk. but its not work. The strangest thing that I do not see these dependencies in build.gradle. There is only 23.0.2

Comment: It has to do with the react-native-fbsdk dependency, not with your project. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40355340/2628463)

Comment: @martinarroyo thanks)

Comment: Gladly :) Did it work?