# Failed to find compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.0.0'

Tags: android

I'm trying to use material design. But  **'com.android.support:design-v7:25.0.0'** is giving the following error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usaukglu.scrollabletab"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.0.0'

}
```

> Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:design-v7:25.0.0 Open File.
>   Open in Project Structure dialog

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'` Then Clean-Rebuild-Gradle

Comment: I did but not working

Comment: Check your sdk manager

Comment: I installed Android Sdk Build tools 25

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321265/android-studio-suddenly-started-to-display-unable-to-resolve-com-android-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace that line with this and it would definitely work.

```
'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Comment: oh no worries. Even i had that issue. Plz upvote and accept the answer as it helped you as a token of gratitude :)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: Open the build.gradle file for your application.

**Step 2:** Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some bug in the v7:25.0.0,(its for nougat) the preview of your layout will not be shown properly, so try to use v7:24.2.1,
but you need to install build tool

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

Comment: i am using the same but i am getting error in android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4

Comment: set minimum sdk version to 15

Comment: i am using  compileSdkVersion 24  minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usaukglu.scrollabletab"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.0.0'
```

}

you had to change  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
to buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

Answer (score -1):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "liefsolutions.com.thebestservice"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'buildToolsVersion 24.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

}